Why does Django still display migrations when none exist?
I'm trying to reset my migrations and start off fresh but I'm getting this really strange issue I can't seem to fix. I started off by deleting the Migrations folder and Deleting every table in Database I'm using (for context it's a MySQL database and I'm using MySQL Workbench to access it). Now after doing so I ran the python manage.py showmigrations command and it keeps showing me all the old migrations even though none should exist.
Here is what I tried to do to fix this issue:

I tried to restart the server multiple times with every change or action I did
I deleted and created the database again with the same name
I deleted and created the database again with a different name
I created an empty Migrations folder in hopes that maybe it would fill up the folder with the files but it does not, and now I have an empty Migrations folder and still an empty database with no tables
I deleted all the __pycache__ folders I could find

I know this isn't database-sided because I re-created the database with a different name as mentioned. I know there is something that is keeping all this data stored even though the Migrations folder is empty and the Database is empty with no tables. How do I fix this?

did you migrate all database?

Share the migrations it is showing and which is marked by an [X] next to the name and which isn’t?

@django.seolpyo.com When i run the makemigrations command it shows no changes and when I run the migration command it gives multiple errors and doesn't migrate any table

@ChukwujiobiCanon When I run showmigrations it shows all the default and custom models that need migrations and none of them have an X because I deleted everything in the Migrations folder and all the tables in the Database.

There you have your answer. There wasn't a problem to begin with. When you have a fresh database, no migrations history and you are just starting out with some custom models written out, the output of show migrations is the migrations that will be applied which are exactly what you observed: "all the default and custom models that need migrations". Those will get migrated. The answer you posted is not a solution because there is no problem to begin with. If you were expecting a different behaviour, explain in detail what that behaviour should be and why.

The output of showmigrations and migrate --plan should complement each other.

I will ask again that you share the output of showmigrations. Also,  share your Django version.

I found a fix for this by recreating the following steps:

Delete the migrations folder
run python manage.py makemigrations --empty <app_name>

When I did this then ran the makemigrations command again it detected all my changes and carried out the migration successfully after running python manage.py migrate.

its because you should not delete migrations folder you need to only delete migrations files. python manage.py makemigrations --empty <app_name> this created new migrations folder for you therefore it started working. you should only delete migration files just leaving __init__.py in the migrations folder

@nabinsademba --empty simply outputs an empty migration for manual editing. It has nothing to do with what you are talking about and it also doesn't answer this question. This answer has simply created a new empty migration that will be commited after editing manually. If commited without editing, it is a no op. This doesn't address the original problem: "I ran the python manage.py showmigrations command and it keeps showing me all the old migrations even though none should exist."
